# How to save text from entry widget into database using insert statement?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to take data from entry fields and save it in the database. I have mentioned 6 columns in my SQL query but I have one more column in database which is ID and it is auto incremented. When I run this script I have no error but also no data gets inserted into the db rather than ID which is auto incremented. Here is my code:

```
window=tkinter.Tk()
# Set the window title
window.title("Princedeep Singh")
window.geometry("500x400")
current_row = 0

# Set the current row to zero

refdate_label = Label(window, text="Enter value for date: ")
refdate_label.grid(row=current_row, column=0)
refdate_text = StringVar()
refdate_entry = Entry(window, textvariable=refdate_text)
refdate_entry.grid(row=current_row, column=1)

current_row += 1

# geogeo field
geo_t_label = Label(window ,text="Enter value for geo:")
geo_t_label.grid(row=current_row, column=0)
geo_t_text = StringVar()
geo_t_entry = Entry(window, textvariable=geo_t_text)
geo_t_entry.grid(row=current_row, column=1)
current_row += 1


# commod field
commod_label = Label(window, text="Enter value for commod:")
commod_label.grid(row=current_row, column=0)
commod_text = StringVar()
commod_entry = Entry(window, textvariable=commod_text)
commod_entry.grid(row=current_row, column=1)
current_row += 1


# vector
vector_label = Label(window, text="Enter value for vector:")
vector_label.grid(row=current_row, column=0)
vector_text = StringVar() 
vector_entry = Entry(window, textvariable=vector_text)
vector_entry.grid(row=current_row, column=1)
current_row += 1



# commod field
coordinate_label = Label(window, text="Enter value for coordinate:")
coordinate_label.grid(row=current_row, column=0)
coordinate_text = StringVar()
coordinate_entry = Entry(window, textvariable=coordinate_text)
print(coordinate_text)
coordinate_entry.grid(row=current_row, column=1)
current_row += 1


value_label = Label(window, text="Enter value :")
value_label.grid(row=current_row, column=0)
value_text = StringVar()
value_entry = Entry(window, textvariable=value_text)
value_entry.grid(row=current_row, column=1)
current_row += 1



conn = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost', db='postgres', user='root', 
       password='root')
cur = conn.cursor()

submit = Button(window, text='submit', command=cur.execute('INSERT INTO 
         record(refdate,geo,commod,vector,coordinate,value) VALUES (%s, %s, 
         %s, %s, %s,%s)',
         (refdate_text.get(),geo_t_text.get(),commod_text.get()
         ,vector_text.get(),str(coordinate_text.get()),value_text.get() )))  
submit.grid(row=current_row+1, column=4)
conn.commit()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! please read up on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
submit = Button(window, text='submit', command=cur.execute('INSERT INTO 
         record(refdate,geo,commod,vector,coordinate,value) VALUES (%s, %s, 
         %s, %s, %s,%s)',
         (refdate_text.get(),geo_t_text.get(),commod_text.get()
         ,vector_text.get(),str(coordinate_text.get()),value_text.get() )))  
submit.grid(row=current_row+1, column=4)
```

You're calling `cur.execute(…)` at creation time, and passing the result as the `command` for the `Button`.

Of course at creation time, the entries are all empty, so you insert an empty row.

And then, the result of `execute` is not a function, so what you store as the `command` is not something that can be called, so clicking the button later does nothing except write a warning to `stderr` that you aren't looking at.

You need to create a function (of no arguments), that you can pass to `command`—a function that, when called, will do this insert for you. For example:

```
def on_submit():
    cur.execute('INSERT INTO record blah blah blah' …, value_text.get()))

submit = Button(window, text='submit', command=on_submit)
```

If you'd prefer to do it all in one giant expression, as in your old code, you can use `lambda` instead of `def`, or use `functools.partial(execute, …)`, but it's probably clearer this way.

Comment: Thanks abarnert for your solution. I followed your answer but i have same issue. I made two seperate functions under class one function has all code listed above other method has db connection and query. I made variables global but don't know how to use variables value from one function to another. Please give me some suggestions.

Comment: @ZimidarBoy That explanation of what you did isn't nearly enough for me to debug it. If you're actually having the same problem after a small change to your code, edit the question. If you're having a similar problem after rewriting your code, post a new question. (You can link to this one to explain why you've done what you did.) Either way, that gives you room to include a complete example that people can debug, and it means your example will be seen by the whole SO Python community instead of just whoever's reading comments under an old answer.